# Vimeo setting tittle through API v3 beta

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I was trying to set title to video using "PATCH" http://api.vimeo.com/videos/
12434124?client_id=124155&title=12515

It throws error "The user is not allowed to perform that action. [Your access token does not have the "edit" scope]."

Any specific settings or permission required to do this?

OR

Any other api to do this?

**Edited:**

Can we set title and description while uploading video, instead of making another api request for edit ? (Upload scope available, but editing scope not available)

Answer (score 0):

When authenticating your user via OAuth 2 you need to request the "edit" scope. This is mentioned in the "Obtaining Authentication credentials" step of the API3 Auth document.

OAuth 2.0 supports this directly, and if you wish to generate your token via the app page, you just need to click the appropriate check boxes.

Comment: No user level authentication. We are using app level. Oauth2 token to access api's

Comment: Can we set title and description while uploading video, instead of making another api request?

Comment: You can not edit or upload videos using the app level tokens, you must use an authenticated access token so that Vimeo knows who the destination user is. Also, title and description can not presently be set in the upload step, but it can happen immediately after the upload completion.

Comment: Dashron, wouldn't the OAuth API3 request need to be made via a login redirect with the user's account? Is there a way to do this with the APP's user account? Seems a bit silly that the video can be uploaded but its title/description not be changed during/after upload